# Why AWS instance not showing the correct storage that is attached externally?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, filesystems

I have attached an external EBS volume of 650GB to my ubuntu instance with a root volume of 250GB.
650GB is attached to /xvdg-volume

[image: the result of lsblk]

But if I check the df -h command it is not displaying the entire volume. You can see that in the following image: /xvdg-volume is only 350GB

[image: the result of df -h]

Does anyone say why this is happening in my case?

Comment: Was this volume extended to 650 from 350?

Comment: @Riz Yes it was increased from 350 to 650 GB

Comment: Please follow this guide. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/extend-linux-file-system/

Comment: @Riz
Thank you so much, dude. I will follow it. But why this is happening if you have time please give some insights

Comment: I am not an expert in this but it's the filesystem. Increase in Volume doesn't reflect changes to OS. You need to extend filesystem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the volume has been extended, the EC2 instance and the system both need to be adjusted to adapt to the new size.

To do this use the `resize2fs` method to resize the changed partition.

In your case will be something like this:

```
sudo resize2fs /xvdg-volume
```

You can also extend the partition and file system size after you have already grown the volume on the AWS side by simply rebooting your instance. When the operating system comes back up, it will modify everything itself.

For more information check here: [How to Resize EBS Volumes on AWS](https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/how-to-increase-the-size-of-an-aws-ebs-cloud-volume-attached-to-a-linux-machine)

Comment: Thank you so much @valdeci
Will it affect the production environment If I resize the fs of the attached external volume?
and one more thing is just restarting the instance will fix all the issue?

Comment: yeah, the resizing will not affect the Production env if you follow the steps properly, also no downtime will be resulted from this process and yeah, if you reboot this process will be done at the restart